# Can I say "Which area of triangle a or triangle b is larger"?

Tags: grammar, questions

I am a math teacher in Asia. In one math question there are two triangles, A and B. I want to ask which has the larger area. Should I ask:

> "Which area of triangle a or triangle b is larger"?

or

> "Which triangle, a or b, has a larger area"?

Answer (score 3):

The second one would be more correct: "Which triangle, A or B, has a larger area?"

However, a better way (in my opinion) to phrase it would be simply "Which triangle has a larger area?", if there are only the triangles A and B to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

The second choice you present is correct as you present it. The first choice would be improved if you eliminate the "of" and enclose "triangle a or trianble b" with commas. The "of" in the first choice as you present it implies that triangle a has more than one area.

Comment: The first sentence is _not_ corrected by saying "Which area, triangle a or triangle b, is larger?" Triangle a is not an _area_. It is a geometrical construction that has area as one of its properties. You could ask "Of triangle a and triangle b, which has the larger area?"

Answer (score 1):

[@tchrist](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195227/can-i-say-which-area-of-triangle-a-or-triangle-b-is-larger#comment410338_195229) is correct, for two triangles one has a *larger* area (we are assuming they don't have the same area). Hence Erik Kowal's, *larger vs. largest* is most definitely not pedantic.

Although using the word *largest* and most of the responses here would likely be understood by the hearer/reader. The phrase:

> Which triangle has the larger area, triangle a or triangle b?"

is excellent grammar, leaves no room for misunderstanding and more importantly, demonstrates good understanding of English.

Comment: Your answer consists of a series of assertions with no underpinning logic or rationale.

Answer (score 0):

"Which triangle, a or b, has **the largest** area?" unambiguously means what it says. (Note the slight modification of your wording.)

"Which area of triangle a or triangle b is larger?" makes it sound as though triangles a and b have been subdivided into smaller areas, and you are asking which of those areas in each triangle is the largest.

Comment: Um, no.  With two triangles, one has the ***larger*** area and one the smaller. Only with three or more is it possible to use *largest*.

Comment: @tchrist - I'm sorry, but the distinction you have drawn is pure scholastic pedantry that ought to have died out before you were even born.

Comment: @ErikKowal: tchrist is correct. Moreover, mathematics demands more precision in usage than other contexts. "Larger than" is a binary operation in mathematics: you check whether _a_ is a greater quantity than _b_ or not. "Largest" implies a _series_ of binary operations, which you do not have.

Comment: @aeismail - We're comparing two areas here, not a series of numbers. My suggested formulation is perfectly apt in this context, and impossible to misinterpret -- though 'larger' would also work, of course, since there are only two triangles. Tchrist's objection to 'largest' is based not on mathematical grounds, but on linguistic pedantry.

Comment: @ErikKowal: It is because we are comparing _two_ areas that "largest" is _mathematically_ inappropriate.

Comment: @aeismail - Why is it inappropriate if it is impossible to misinterpret?

Comment: @ErikKowal: Because when you have two numbers a and b, a is   either smaller than b, equal to b, or larger than b. These are all uniquely representable mathematically, and is what the question is formally asking: ("Is area(a) > area(b)?") "Largest" doesn't have the same simple mathematical interpretation, and therefore complicates the mathematics, in exchange for marginal linguistic simplification.